# !important для всего блока css

Tags: html, css, css3, оформление

Подскажите, есть ли в css возможность выставления свойства `!important` сразу для всех свойств.

Сейчас мне приходится писать так:

```
.btn-disabled {
  background: #eaeaea !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  cursor: default !important;
}
```

Но может есть какой-нибудь способ сказать, что всё, что указано в `.btn-disabled` имеет свойство `!important`?

Comment: Дико интересно на кой всем правилам задавать `!important`?

Comment: например есть активная кнопка, хочу сделать неактивную
задаю как 
`<div class = 'btn btn-disabled'>`, при описании свойства `btn-disabled` указываю только те, которые надо переопределить и так, чтобы перестали действовать всякие `.btn:hover` - для этого и `!important`, чтобы не плодить `.btn-disabled:hover` и т.п.

Comment: Да вы батенька...  Я лучше промолчу... Что за чушь...  Достаточно грамотно в css   стили описать...

Comment: Неверный путь. Пропишите в `btn` геометрию. В `btn-common` - еще более детальные вещи, и в `btn-disabled` не придется ничего писать. Ну и `.btn-disabled:hover` - всего лишь частный случай, пропишите такие правила, и надобность в `btn-common` отпадет.

Comment: `!important` - надо использовать там где надо, а не там где хочется...

Comment: @TotalPusher, дело говорит....

Comment: И отдельным комментом - если вам просто лень писать `!important`, возьмите препроцессор, напишите миксину, будет что-то типа `importants { селекторы и свойства, которым добавится important }`

Comment: Для `btn-disabled` пропишите `pointer-events: none` и не будет никакого ховера не нем. Вообще использование !important очень плохой тон, который говорит что вы в бардаке утонули уже

Comment: Приведи конкретный пример из того, что делаешь и опиши, как хочешь чтобы было...  Поможем укажем, как правильнее реализовать...

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии, учту. В основном как раз такое пришлось писать из-за того, чтобы не плодить `:hover`, `:focus`. Т.е. стиль объекта разбить на 2 стиля - 1) общий внешний вид и 2) стиль состояния, по идее тогда и `:hover` я просто на стиль состояния тогда навешиваю. Единственное, придется 2 `toggleClass` вместо 1 делать, но это уже не критично, как я думаю.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нет такого.Пишите !important отдельно для каждого свойства.

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать "вес" селекторов css, использовать цепочки селекторов. `important` используем когда нет возможности написать правила правильно, или для исключительных случаев.

можно представить, что

- `p` - один селектор это 1 бал
- `div p` - это 2 бала
- `.class` - класс это 10
- `#id` -  идентификатор это 100

тогда

- body(1) #id(100) .class(10) p(1) === 112
- body(1) p(1) === 2

Этого вполне достаточно, чтобы правильно спланировать свою структуру.

`!important` может (но не обязательно) потенциально создать трудности при переопределении стилей в будущем. Поэтому его нужно использовать именно для "важных" значений, которые не должны переопределятся или имеют особый приоритет.

```css
.wrapper {
  color: red;
}

.list {
  color: green;
}

.btn {
   color: blue;
}

.wrapper .btn {
  color: orange;
}

.wrapper .list .btn {
  color: yellow;
}

.wrapper .list .ul li:first-child > a.btn {
  color: black;
}


#btn {
 color: violet;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="list">
     <ul class="ul">
        <li><a class="btn">ul .btn</a></li>
        <li><a class="btn">ul .btn</a></li>
        <li><a class="btn" id="btn">#btn</a></li>
     </ul>
     <p>.list p</p>
  </div>
  <p>.wrapper p</p>
</div>
```

Comment: А еще лучше отказаться от каскада и верстать по БЭМ

Comment: Одно не исключает другого. Нужно знать и понимать основы. БЭМ лишь методология, соглашение по "именованию и использованию классов". Но конечно бэм - это отличный пример хорошей практики.

Comment: не спорю, я лишь дополнил ваш ответ